I have recovered funds, but have no idea how to move them using docker etc
i have managed to retrieve the funds to my wallet that was sent to the wrong chain - the funds are there but now I am unable to move them.  So I have downloaded docker and tried my best many times to follow the instructions, but tbh I really am clueless, I really need a straight easy how to to go from having docker, what commands on what container and how to move them to another wallet. I am really hoping someone can please assist

also, it is on BASE chain

Why do you need docker to move funds from one wallet to another? Is it on an EVM chain? Do you have it's private Key?
Can you provide any more details for it?
